# Change yolov3 installation path | cv2

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I am currently trying to set up a python script that should detect objects from a raspberrypi via a tcp socket. 
This is how I currently just display the image in a window:

```
global footage_socket, font, frame_num, fps

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
while True:
    frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
    img = base64.b64decode(frame)
    npimg = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Livebild des RaspTanks", source)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

But here comes the problem: When trying to implement object recognition using **detect_common_objects** of cvlib i am getting the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-
python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:207: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to 
parse NetParameter file: C:\Users\Büro\.cvlib\object_detection\yolo\yolov3\yolov3.cfg in function 
'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190902::readNetFromDarknet
```

I think this happens because of the 'ü' in my username. Is there a way to change the yolov3 path or an other solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your *.cfg* file in the directory you coded? I dont think its about "ü" letter. Just change the *.cfg* file directory to be sure.

Comment: I double-check the file now: It is in fact there. I would have changed the directory yet, if i knew how

Comment: Just copy .cfg file to another directory

Comment: I think you dont understand. I dont know how to tell opencv in python which directionary the config file is in